# JQGrid Date Formatting Issue

Tags: jquery, date, jqgrid

Recently we came across an issue where dates were being represented incorrectly by jQGrid. There were other dates in the table that seemed to work perfectly fine.
However, certain dates were failing.

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2pb84qk/) for a demo of the problem.
Note that the input date value is "10/24/2015" with format for jQGrid as "m/d/Y". The output in the table however is "06/06/2017".

The column definition for the date column looks like this: (fiddle is forked from one written by Oleg himself).

```
    {
        name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', search: false, editable: true, align: "left", width: 75, 
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return cellvalue === null ? "N/A" : $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellvalue, options, rowObject);
        }, formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" }
    }
```

I am still analyzing the source code to understand how jQgrid formats dates. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to have `srcFormat` in the `formatoptions` too:

```
formatoptions: {
    srcformat: "m/d/Y", //<----add this too
    newformat: "m/d/Y"
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2pb84qk/1/)

Comment: I feel stupid now :). Thank you so much. What is the default srcformat though?

Comment: same as i can see you have `10/24/2015` which is `m/d/Y` and `srcformat` is a requirement in the updated jQgrid libs.